# git recovering a project

Tags: git, github

I created a Visual Studio project years ago and commited it to a git repository in dropbox.  I've sinced lost the origional project but have found the origional git repo.  I want to recover my project.  How to I pull all files from the repo to a new project file.  When I try to "pull" or "Fetch" using Tortoicegit I get a popup menu without any approate options.  I'm a bit embarrased but I've run out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Bruce - can you clarify a couple points? 1) where is the repo you found? Is it on github, somewhere local, another hosted location?  2) When you use tortoise git you should first `clone` the repository you intend to pull from; did you do that?

Comment: Hi John: It was a local repo.  I did clone it first but I'm not sure now if I was trying to get it from the clone or the original.  The original is on my dropbox directory and the clone is on in my documents directory.  What I did discover though is that "SOMEHOW" I did something and it pulled/fetched or what ever happened but the next time I went in to my VS project directory it was there.  Wish I knew why but it just happened.  I do appreciate your response.  I guess what I should probably do is create a test project and try to push and pull and fetch and learn how to do it correctly.